# Oracle Scheduler Jobs with multiple frequency

Tags: sql, oracle, dbms-job

I am creating Scheduler Jobs for doing Backup via stored procedure and I am in kind of a situation that, the user will be selecting multiple frequencies like

In first case user selects Monthly as frequency of Job.

In second case user selects Weekly as frequency of Job(May be of different day combinations).

In third case user selects Daily as frequency of Job and so on.

So as per now there are 3(may be more as per the user schedules it) frequency for the same job. What's the best way to do this?
I've to schedule same job with multiple frequencies or any other better way.

Comment: I think the best and clean way to achieve it is to create 3 different JOBS for different frequencies and enable/disable them according to input from the user.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.That's the way I thought too but just wanted to know is there a better way to achieve this.

Comment: I assume you are running different commands. Would be strange to run the same command on different frequencies. If so, you would have to create one job for each frequency.

Comment: Bear in mind, the Daily job will execute also weekly and monthly, so why do you need multiple frequencies?

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit I went with multiple jobs with different frequencies. I have to do it because we are not aware of what all patterns the user needs to run.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best and clean way to achieve it is to create 3 different JOBS for different frequencies and enable/disable them according to input from the user

How to enable/disable job in PL/SQL:

```
BEGIN
dbms_scheduler.disable('<JOB_NAME>');
END;
/

BEGIN
dbms_scheduler.enable('<JOB_NAME>');
END;
/
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a procedure and based on user's input you can dynamically change the parameters in the following:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name           =>  'job_name',
   job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
   job_action         =>  'PROCEDURE_NAME',
   start_date         =>  'START_DATE',
   repeat_interval    =>  'FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1', /* every other day */
   end_date           =>  'END_DATE',
   auto_drop          =>   FALSE,
   comments           =>  'My new job');
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. What if the user want to schedule the same job yearly, monthly and weekly (on all Monday) ?

Comment: Then you can create multiple jobs for same procedure as ultimately you want to execute procedure only. You can not mention `DAILY and MONTHLY` together in single job.